# Why my training Precision and Recall is higher than Validation Precision and Recall?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-networks, classification

I am training a deep learning model for binary image classification using `Keras` and `TensorFlow`. My model gave the highest `acc` and lower `loss`. The other metrics I used also have higher values like `precision` and `recall`.

As I used the generator and I mentioned the validation set during fitting the model. So the precision and `recall` on `validation` data are just **50%**. But the `Confusion metric` is not that much worse on test data. What should I assume that my model is overfitting?

Here is my few epochs logs:

```py
Epoch 00042: LearningRateScheduler setting learning rate to 8.28633770088062e-06.
595/595 [==============================] - 1871s 3s/step - loss: 0.0162 - accuracy: 0.9952 - precision_m: 0.9958 - recall_m: 0.9936 - f1_m: 0.9942 - val_loss: 0.1693 - val_accuracy: 0.9637 - val_precision_m: 0.5000 - val_recall_m: 0.4797 - val_f1_m: 0.4891

Epoch 00042: saving model to /home/ali/Desktop/pneumonia classification/Final Dataset/RSNA/model_training_512_finetune_3.h5
Epoch 43/50

Epoch 00043: LearningRateScheduler setting learning rate to 7.497788410238852e-06.
595/595 [==============================] - 2167s 4s/step - loss: 0.0147 - accuracy: 0.9952 - precision_m: 0.9968 - recall_m: 0.9944 - f1_m: 0.9953 - val_loss: 0.1673 - val_accuracy: 0.9645 - val_precision_m: 0.5000 - val_recall_m: 0.4823 - val_f1_m: 0.4904

Epoch 00043: saving model to /home/ali/Desktop/pneumonia classification/Final Dataset/RSNA/model_training_512_finetune_3.h5
Epoch 44/50

Epoch 00044: LearningRateScheduler setting learning rate to 6.784279506100467e-06.
595/595 [==============================] - 2405s 4s/step - loss: 0.0125 - accuracy: 0.9967 - precision_m: 0.9982 - recall_m: 0.9958 - f1_m: 0.9968 - val_loss: 0.1676 - val_accuracy: 0.9671 - val_precision_m: 0.5000 - val_recall_m: 0.4831 - val_f1_m: 0.4909
```

Comment: Please notice that getting something "urgent" is not a justification for posting off-topic questions. Plus, please see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) (tl;dr: **no**).

Answer (score 1):

This shows that your model is overfit. It means it is learning but not applying generally on any other data than the training it self. To prevent this type of problem you have to apply some techniques to prevent from overfit.

1. Perform Hyperparameter tunning in Nueral networks
2. Regularization
3. Apply Early stopping in Fit method
4. Get more training and test data
5. Use ensemble learning as not every problem has to be solved by neural nets

One more thing, If your data is images then use Data Augmentation before training with keras.

Comment: Try anything you havent used. It takes time but eventually you will get to better test recall and precision. as recall is the most important.

Comment: Hyperparamters is tunned for this model.
`ResNet50v2` already contains BN and dropout.
Early stopping is applied.
I have `20GB` of data I think it's enough for this model.
Ensemble learning is applied when you want to use multiple models for a single task to improve results. (useless for now)

Comment: Can you tell me how many classes you have in your dataset?

Comment: It's a binary classification problem having a balanced dataset. It's chest Xrays where data have very limited diversity in a normal and infected persons.